# main.worker.js? What's that?

Tags: pdf, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, pdf.js

I am building a PDF viewer in Ionic 2 using the [Mozilla PDF Viewer](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) but have run into a problem. I have built `pdf.js` in accordance with [these instructions](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/#building-pdfjs). The code generated includes this line:

```
var worker = new Worker(workerSrc);
```

Chrome is complaining on this line that it cannot find the file `GET http://localhost:8100/build/main.worker.js`.

Now then, I have not come across web workers before, so I'm not sure what this error means or where to find, or build, this file. I notice that the build process also yields a file called `pdf.worker.js`, and I have strong suspicions that this might be the file it's after, although renaming it to `main.worker.js` had no effect.

I'm sure this is a very simple problem if you are in the know. What am I missing?

---

Ok, after a little more digging, I found [this](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-pdf.js-in-a-website) which pertains more to my situation. I am using Ionic 2 and I don't know how to generate the file referenced in this line:

```
pdfjsLib.PDFJS.workerSrc = '../../build/webpack/pdf.worker.bundle.js';
```

Can anyone illuminate my dark mind?

Comment: Check out the ionic conference app and the service worker there https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/service-worker.js

Comment: The main PDF.js repo does not contain built pdf.js/pdf.worker.js files -- they are published at pdfjs-dist repo. There is a chance you can use non-build src/ files, but you need to know how pdf.js is made and replicate the similar build process in Ionic 2

Comment: @serlingpa did you ever managed to find how to do this correctly ?